# Astar pathfinding sometimes stops working

Tags: a-star

I'm doing a project when i need to search a path in maze ( matrix of 0's and 1's ), given a origin ( a position tuple ) and an destination. 
It works, but sometimes it's just stops, enters in the while loop and while opening the nodes, never reaches the end node... and i don't know why.
I find that algorithm on "medium" site.

´´´

def astar(maze, start, end,bonus,exit_door):

```
maze = [ [0 if x == 0 else 1 for x in y] for y in maze ]
x_end=end[0]
y_end=end[1]
maze[x_end][y_end]=0
if bonus:
    x_bonus=bonus[0]
    y_bonus=bonus[1]
    maze[x_bonus][y_bonus]=0
if exit_door:
    x_exit=exit_door[0]
    y_exit=exit_door[1]
    maze[x_exit][y_exit]=0




# Create start and end node
start_node = Node(None, start)

start_node.g = start_node.h = start_node.f = 0
end_node = Node(None, end)

end_node.g = end_node.h = end_node.f = 0

# Initialize both open and closed list
open_list = []
closed_list = []

# Add the start node
open_list.append(start_node)


# Loop until you find the end
while len(open_list) > 0 :

    tempo=tempo+1
    # Get the current node
    current_node = open_list[0]

    current_index = 0
    for index, item in enumerate(open_list):
        if item.f <= current_node.f:

            current_node = item
            current_index = index

    # Pop current off open list, add to closed list
    open_list.pop(current_index)

    closed_list.append(current_node)

    # Found the goal
    if current_node == end_node:

        path = []
        current = current_node
        while current is not None:
            path.append(current.position)
            current = current.parent

        return path[::-1] # Return reversed path










    # Generate children
    children = []
    ####
    for new_position in [(0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0)]: # Adjacent squares

        # Get node position
        node_position = (current_node.position[0] + new_position[0], current_node.position[1] + new_position[1])
        ## vê cada quadrado adjacente ao nosso current

        # Make sure within range
        if node_position[0] > (len(maze) - 1) or node_position[0] < 0 or node_position[1] > (len(maze[len(maze)-1]) -1) or node_position[1] < 0:
            continue

        # Make sure walkable terrain
        if maze[node_position[0]][node_position[1]] != 0:
            continue

        # Create new node
        new_node = Node(current_node, node_position)

        # Append
        children.append(new_node)
        ## children apenas contém os nós que correspondem a quadrados para o quais o agente pode andar

    # Loop through children
    for child in children:

        # Child is on the closed list
        for closed_child in closed_list:
            if child == closed_child:

                continue

        # Create the f, g, and h values
        child.g = current_node.g + 1
        child.h = ((child.position[0] - end_node.position[0]) ** 2) + ((child.position[1] - end_node.position[1]) ** 2)
        child.f = child.g + child.h

        # Child is already in the open list
        for open_node in open_list:
            if child == open_node and child.g > open_node.g:
                continue

        # Add the child to the open list
        open_list.append(child)
```

´´´

Answer (score 1):

This is not working becouse u have 2 misstake

```
 for closed_child in closed_list:
        if child == closed_child:
            continue
```

and

```
for open_node in open_list:
        if child == open_node and child.g > open_node.g:
            continue
```

operator `continue` exits iner for. You should use another type for open_list and closed_list.